# Can I use cd../.. as an alias name?

Tags: bash, alias

I am using Windows and Ubuntu in parallel and do console stuff on both of them.

On Windows I can do a

```
C:\Users\Thomas>cd..\..
C:\>
```

However, on Linux this does not work, neither with backslashes nor with forward slashes.

```
21:17:10 $ cd../..
bash: cd../..: No such file or directory
```

Since I often make that mistake, I have tried to define an alias in `.bash_aliases` for that situation:

```
alias cd../..='cd ../..'
alias cd..\..='cd ../..'
```

When I start a new bash, I get

```
21:16:26 $ bash
bash: alias: `cd../..': invalid alias name
```

How would I set up aliases for `cd..\..` and `cd../..` correctly?

The `cd..\..` seems to have problems with the escape character:

```
21:39:43 $ cd..\..
bash: cd....: command not found
```

It does not work, even if I define another alias for `cd....`.

Comment: You can't. A command, alias or filename cannot contain the `/` character. The `\ ` version, on the other hand, should work fine.

Comment: @fkraiem: It seems the backslash version has problems as escape character. Updated the question.

Comment: Oh, indeed. From `man bash`: *The characters /, $, \`, and = and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters        listed above may not appear in an alias name.*

Comment: Damn. I tried `man alias` and it didn't exist. If you give that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Aliases are one thing, shell functions are another. Have another look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/` and `\` are among the characters which cannot appear in a Bash alias name. From `man bash`:

> The characters `/`, `$`, `, and `=` and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an alias name.

As a workaround, you can switch to Zsh, which allows both:

```
% grep 'alias.*cd' .zshrc 
alias cd../..='cd ../..'
alias cd..\\..='cd ../..'
% pwd
/Users/firas
% cd../..
% pwd
/ 
% cd
% pwd
/Users/firas
% cd..\..
% pwd
/
```

Comment: so `alias cd..='cd ..'` works, it enough for me

Answer (score 13):

You can't use slashes in an alias name. Bash allows them in function names, however, so you can make that a function:

```
cd../.. () { cd ../..; }
```

You can't use backslashes in an alias or function name. The backslash character quotes the next character, so `cd..\..` is parsed as `cd....`, well before that string is looked up as a command name. If you want to call a command named `cd..\..`, you need to type `cd..\\..`, `'cd..\..'`, or something equivalent. Furthermore, a command name which was quoted in any way isn't considered for alias lookup, so you can't ever use an alias name containing a backslash. Bash doesn't allow backslashes in function names, either. Since `cd..\..` is parsed as `cd....`, you can define a function called `cd....` (as above).

If you use the `cd` command, you'll have to type the space after it, just like any other command. But you can save typing by not typing `cd` at all. Set the `autocd` option with the following line in `~/.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

Then you can type a directory name on the command line, and “executing” that directory will change to it.

```
~/some/sub/directory$ ../..
~/some$
```

Comment: If I do the `shopt` thing, I'll probably miss that functionality on Windows soon :-)

Comment: Um, that's not true. Slashes are accepted in bash function names.

Comment: @alexis Ah, right, you can use slashes in bash. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: @ThomasW. Of course you will. `autocd` was one of the reasons I switched to zsh, back when bash didn't have it. The only decent way to use Windows is to install Cygwin anyway, complete with zsh.

Answer (score 5):

"You can't use slashes in an alias *or function* name"? That's news to me. I've been using the following shell function for years on Linux and OS X bash, and never had any trouble:

```
function ../.. { cd ../..; echo "$PWD"; }
```

Naturally, `cd../..` is a fine function name as well. A slash *can* be used in a shell function name.

As for the backslash version, you can't embed it in an alias or function name but you don't have to: When you type `cd..\..`, bash interprets the backslash as an escape and tries to execute the resulting `cd....`. So define that and you can do everything you were after. You are welcome.

```
function cd.... { cd ../..; }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the aliases, why not just do:

```
alias   ..='cd ..'
alias  ...='cd ../../' 
alias ....='cd ../../../'
```

Or, if you need to go *way* back:

```
alias   .3='cd ../../../' 
alias   .4='cd ../../../../'
alias   .5='cd ../../../../../'
# how far back do you need to go on a normal basis..?
```

No idea how well that helps you keep mentally in sync with your Windows brain, but this still seems like a simple way to go.  (At least for those of us lucky enough to not need to worry about how things are done on Windows.)